# css odd/even pair on class selector for jquerymobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Trying to set the first slider with a width of 20% and second with 75%

http://jsfiddle.net/kE8GJ/5/

Seems I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, if you look at the generated code, jQuery automatically inserts generated markup into your HTML as so:

```
<div data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main" style="
    width: 300px;
    background: blue;
">
        <h2> List </h2>
            <select data-theme="b" data-mini="true" name="slider2" id="flip-a2" data-role="slider" onchange="" class="ui-slider-switch">
                <option value="3">something</option>
                <option value="0">name</option>
            </select><div role="application" class="ui-slider ui-slider-switch ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-corner-all ui-slider-mini" style=""><span class="ui-slider-label ui-slider-label-a ui-btn-active ui-btn-corner-all" role="img" style="width: 100%; ">name</span><span class="ui-slider-label ui-slider-label-b ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-corner-all" role="img" style="width: 0%; ">something</span><div class="ui-slider-inneroffset"><a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-slider-handle-snapping ui-btn-up-b" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="b" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="1" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuetext="name" title="name" aria-labelledby="flip-a2-label" style="left: 100%; "><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text"></span></span></a></div></div>

            <select data-theme="e" data-mini="true" name="slider" id="flip-a" data-role="slider" onchange="" class="ui-slider-switch">
                <option value="3">gkhkj</option>
                <option value="0">ok</option>
            </select><div role="application" class="ui-slider ui-slider-switch ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-corner-all ui-slider-mini" style=""><span class="ui-slider-label ui-slider-label-a ui-btn-active ui-btn-corner-all" role="img" style="width: 100%; ">ok</span><span class="ui-slider-label ui-slider-label-b ui-btn-down-c ui-btn-corner-all" role="img" style="width: 0%; ">gkhkj</span><div class="ui-slider-inneroffset"><a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-btn ui-btn-up-e ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-slider-handle-snapping" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="e" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="1" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuetext="ok" title="ok" aria-labelledby="flip-a-label" style="left: 100%; "><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text"></span></span></a></div></div> 
    </div>
```

So both your "even" selectors were being hit. You could use ":nth-child(4n+2)" and ":nth-child(4n+4) to select the right pattern, but at that point you're tightly coupling your markup to your css so you may not want to do that.

Added JS fiddle for your specific example accounting for the H2 on top http://jsfiddle.net/kE8GJ/10/